# How to copy multiple files from different directories from local machine to remote machine at a time using scp task in ant?

Tags: ant, scp

Using SCP task in ant, I can transfer one file from local machine to remote machine. 
Referred URL :https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html
But how to copy multiple files from different directories from local machine to remote machine at a time using scp task in ant?

Comment: Have you tried using a nested `fileset`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, as per my understanding, "fileset" is used to copy multiple files into single location. But I want to copy multiple files into multiple lications.